# How to unmarshal escape characters properly with jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, html-escape-characters

I need to unmarshal the below XML which I get from external system as byte array.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Results status="NotProcessed">
    <Error>
        <Message code="SOAP-ENV:Client">HttpCommunicationException</Message>
        <Element>&lt;![CDATA[<detail xmlns="" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <ErrorReport>
                        ABC
                </ErrorReport>
            </detail>]]&gt;</Element>
    </Error>
</Results>
<Response>
```

My classes look like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Response")
public class Response  {
@XmlElement(name = "Results")
protected Results results;

public Results getResults() {
    return this.results;
}

public void setResults(Results value) {
    this.results = value;
}
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Results")
public class Results {
@XmlElement(name = "Error")
protected List<ProblemInformation> error;

public List<ProblemInformation> getError() {
    if (this.error == null) {
        this.error = new ArrayList();
    }
    return this.error;
}
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ProblemInformation")
public class ProblemInformation {
@XmlElement(name = "Message")
protected List<MessageCondition> message;
@XmlElement(name = "Element")
protected String element;

public List<MessageCondition> getMessage() {
    if (this.message == null) {
        this.message = new ArrayList();
    }

    return this.message;
}

public String getElement() {
    return this.element;
}

public void setElement(String value) {
    this.element = value;
}
}
```

After whole process

```
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = contextProvider.getContext().createUnmarshaller();
Object o = unmarshaller.unmarshal(input);
```

in object in field element I have:

```
]]>
```

instead of:

```
<detail xmlns="" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <ErrorReport>
        ABC
    </ErrorReport>
</detail>
```

When I replace `&lt;` with <, and `&gt;` with >, everything works properly. 
Is there any way to unmarshal mentioned XML the way I want? I know that I can turn byte array to String, replace wrong chars, and get new byte array, 
but I don't know if this is a good solution.